# Website Hosting/Registration

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am planning to launch a website down soon. I wanted to know what solutions are available for hosting and registration.

- Starting with domain registration. Any site you have used/preferred ?  I am considering either godaddy or 123reg. Does it even make any difference which you choose? Is there any fine print i need to worry about. I am based in UK , not sure if that helps in resolving any issues if encountered.
- Does my hosting need to be done at the site i purchased my registration? If not , will there be any transfer fees if i change my hosting? Can I just register the name now and worry about hosting later?
- At the moment, I plan to have it up and running using either some sort of a tool or a template and perhaps put the bells and whistles down the line. I understand 123 has its own builder tool available, There are a few solutions suggested like wordpress,drupal & jhoomla... I am a C++ developer , not a web programmer, but I do feel the need to open the hood up and make changes if i see fit. So I guess I am looking for a solution where I can easily drag-drop widgets I need and when the time comes customize it. Which CMS would you recommend.
- Extras: What extras do you need to get , I was suggested to get hold of whois privacy to keep the spambots away, anything else you guys would recommend I keep my eyes open before I sign the dotted line.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles : It is a good start, it does not answer what i am looking for unfortunately. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: If you click the FAQ link on the questions page you'll find that all of your questions are answered there.